# TexLive 2014 iso file doesn't work to install it

Tags: installing, texlive

I am trying to install TexLive 2014 on my Windows XP. I create virtual drive with the iso.torrent file downloaded from here `http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/Images/` And then nothing works. On my computer there is created virtual disk TexLive 2014 but when I open it I receive message that "no access to the image file".

From different mirrors I tried another downloaded .iso files, not torrent files, I checked md5, everything is matched but still the same issue.

When I do the same procedure with TexLive2012.iso file everything works. What I am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about installing it over the Internet rather than the ISO?

Comment: I have very slow internet connection and my computer is too old and slow. ISO is more suitable for me.

Comment: Assuming the ISO isn't corrupted, you should be able to extract its contents with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html). No need to mount anything explicitly. If the contents extract correctly, you can continue with the installation. If they don't, then you most likely have a corrupted download.

Comment: @MikeRenfro OMG! What to do with all these extracted files? I am not good at such software installations. How do I know that extracted files are completed. Ok, the size of the extracted files is the same 2.7GB, probably this means that the contents is full. Is there any installation instructions (step by step)?

Comment: @MikeRenfro Ah, do I need to double click on Install-tl-windows and proceed it?

Comment: @MikeRenfro I found answer on my question in http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-180003.1.3. Yes, the install-tl-windows is the file to install. Many thanks!

Comment: Well, we thought that `install-tl-windows.exe` is easy enough a name to find. Should we call it `click-me-click-me-to-install-texlive-on-windows`? Just kidding ;-)

Comment: @norbert :) Ah, this would be the perfect name! I do appologize for my dummy question. I was doing my homework really hard, reading The TeXLive Guide but couldn't understand it. Probably due to my fear before installations. Now I know it and have no fear and can understand instructions. Many thanks for understanding, patience and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with the autorun.inf file in TeXLive 2014. The instruction `OPEN=install-tl.bat` should be `OPEN=install-windows-tl.bat`.

If you extract its content, you only have to double-click `install-windows-tl.bat`.